How can I create a CriteriaUpdate query where I select the 'id' column if a method its true which changes another column in its table?
I have a Java 8 project. I have a Server class containing:
Long id
string name
string ipAddress
String status

Its an entity to a SQL database. I want to run a criteriaUpdate query that updates my table based on the method outcome. If 'id' 1 cant be pinged, how do I change the 'status' column without changing all the other 'id' columns to.
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<ServersDao> cu = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(ServersDao.class);
Root<ServersDao> root = cu.from(ServersDao.class);
cu.set("status", "SERVER_UP");
cu.where(cb.equal(root.get("status", "SERVER_DOWN")));

The problem I have is this changes all my rows in my column to either SERVER_UP or SERVER_DOWN. I need thsi to be based on the relative 'id' field, not for all my other id's.
List<ServersDao> servers = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        return servers.stream()
         .map( s -> {
             ServersDto server = new ServersDto();
             server.setNodeId(s.getNodeId());
             server.setName(s.getName());
             server.setIpAddress(s.getIpAddress());
             server.setDescription(s.getDescription());
             server.setStatus(s.getStatus().name());
            
        InetAddress inetAddress = null;
            try {
                inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(s.getIpAddress());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             try {
                if(inetAddress.isReachable(100)) {
                     
                entityManager.createQuery(cu).executeUpdate();
                 }else {
               entityManager.createQuery(cu2).executeUpdate();
                 }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
             return server;

         }).collect(Collectors.toList());


You have several options:

You fetch all your servers, ping them, split the result into two lists "up" and "down", then update your table twice with the use of "in" operator.
You fetch all your servers, then in a loop ping each and update it's object that is still attached to the database.

For case 1 you could do the two updates in one transaction, but I would not include the "fetch all your servers" in that transaction since this will make the transaction very long-running. You could try that of course, but I would expect trouble if multiple accesses to that table happen.
For case 2 you should do each update in a separate transaction, this will be more tricky and also does not give you a "one-time" shot of the servers states, but on the other hand in case 1 also servers could e.g. go down that were just up, while you still ping them.
I don't see that you can or should do an update-query that incoroporates live results from a function.
If the database server that you actually use has a built in function to do the check of the remote server, you could make use of this to let it all happen within one operation, but as network operations usually take quite some time I really would recommend to not do it all in one (ping + update).

I have added the current code how I have the method set up at the moment. So would you suggest doing a 'forEach' in the stream i have set up?
I will need to put this on a timed schedule to, so that everything keeps getting pinged every 30 seconds or so, and update the relevant columns of each 'ids' 'status' column.

Please add your need for the periodic updates into your question so I can update my answer. For the loop you showed: your don't need to execute the whole updatequery for each individual host you test - you simply can modify the value in the object you process in the stream - this will automatically reflect in the database. Just make sure you put transactions on the right place. (Depends on your amount of data and on several other factors.)

at the moment currently my code is changing all my 'ids' to the same status rather than looping through each row individually. Thats my first problem. Once that is solved I would like the method to keep running periodically so the database repeatedly gets updated, so the status of each id changes if say a server gets turned off.
I got this working just using SQL statemtns with a while loop against the resultset. But I dont want to use SQL queries, I want to achieve this by JPQL or criteriaBuilder.

I see what your code does - it executes an update query for all entries so in the end all entries will have the online-state of the last queried server. And as I wrote as one option in my answer and wrote again in my comment, you should not execute that query, but change the state of the ServersDao object you are currently processing in the stream.

how do you mean change the state?

call setStatus
